# Do effects of the Paladin's Shield stack?

Tags: terraria

The [Paladin's Shield](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Paladin%27s_Shield) wiki page states:

> transfers 25% of the damage inflicted on allies to the wearer when
>   its health is above 25%. Allies must be in the same team color for it
>   to work. It gives the most base defense of all accessories with up to
>   10 defense available if reforged to warding

I haven't yet hit Hardmode yet (still have to defeat Eye of Chtulu). What I want to know is, if I have 3 other teammates, and they all have Paladin Shields, theoretically, is the damage taken by anyone (as long as above 25%) literall nill?

If not, what's the "progression" on these things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having more than 1 party member in range equipped with a Paladin's Shield will not provide any additional benefits.